# How do I route an ODBC connection through a Proxy to get around a company firewall? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, python-requests, amazon-redshift

I am trying to access an external Amazon Redshift DB. I am using psycopg2 to access the external postgres db. As far as I know, I cannot include a proxy list as a connection parameter. The below code works when I am not connected to my company VPN.

Is there a way to do this strictly in python? I will be running this code on an on-prem Caas/VM so I would like to avoid machine level solutions such as Putty.

I have tried setting http/https proxies explicitly within my python code but this does not solve my problem. Is this because they are only useful for web API requests?

[Sample Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGTBV.png)

I am open to using alternative libraries.

Comment: Psycopg2 does not use ODBC. It uses the native Postgres protocol.

Comment: Is the proxy you can use e.g. a SOCKS proxy, or..?